# context initialization failed - tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat9

I am getting an error when I am trying to run my spring app. This code is running fine in tomcat7 but getting this error in tomcat9.
p.s.: running inside container

> ERROR:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'xxxxx': Injection of resource dependencies
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type [x.x.x.x] found for dependency: expected at
> least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
> dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=,
> description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class
> java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}

Comment: Looks , you forgot to add @ComponentScan(basePackages = "") in config file

Comment: I have already added that ,There is some tomcat9 additional configuration that I may be missing out.